# How do I use a yaml anchor in an Ansible when conditional?

Tags: ansible, yaml, conditional-statements, anchor

I'm trying to check the value of a variable in a role, but I don't know what the variable name will be beforehand, as it is set outside the role.

I tried to use a yaml anchor to achieve this like so:

```
- set_fact:
    set_anchor: &job_status_data_key "{{ job_running_check_key }}"
[...]
- name: Set current state
  set_fact:
    loop_finished_successfully: true
  when: *job_status_data_key != "Running"
```

Where `job_running_check_key`  at the start, is set outside the role and contains the variable name I'll be checking against.

but ansible appears not to appreciate pointers in the conditionals

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in 'path/to/role/task.yml': line 15, column 30, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    loop_finished_succesfully: true
  when: *job_status_data_key != "Running"
                             ^ here
```

There's probably a proper syntax to achieve this, but I haven't managed to figure it out until now.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing ansible features with YAML features.
A YAML alias is a reference to an existing node. An ansible condition is a Jinja2 expression without quotes.

YAML doesn't know about ansible or Jinja. A YAML alias must be part of the YAML structure. Jinja, on the other hand, does not know about YAML. The consequences are:

```
*job_status_data_key != "Running"
```

is invalid YAML. The YAML syntax defines that an alias starts with `*` and contains a single name of an anchor. The following `!=…` content is therefore a syntax error. Now you might think „okay, let's quote it then so that YAML reads it as string and Jinja can evaluate it“:

```
'*job_status_data_key != "Running"'
```

This is now a valid YAML scalar. If given as value for `when:`, it will be evaluated as Jinja expression. The thing is, Jinja doesn't know that `*job_status_data_key` is supposed to be a YAML alias and in fact, at the time this expression is evaluated, the information about the anchored value of that name has already vanished.

The bottom line is: Don't use anchors and aliases for variables. They are a tool designed for serializing cyclic data structures inside YAML. Ansible offers [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and you should use those instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Obviously I'm already using ansible variables :), but I don't see a way to achieve what I want using ansible variables as there's no way to perform a conditional based on the value of the value of a variable.

I did implement a different approach anyway, which doesn't involve anchors, but I was hoping to have something more elegant. Oh well :)

Comment: @Db0 I don't fully understand your problem because even if the code you show worked, it would simply replace `*job_status_data_key` with `"{{ job_running_check_key }}"` so I don't quite see why you can't write that directly.

Comment: When I tried that, ansible started complaining that this is not cool

Comment: @Db0 Yeah actually it should be just `job_status_data_key` since `when` already contains a Jinja expression.

Comment: That will then compare against the name of the variable I want to compare.

`job_running_check_key` contains the name of a variable. I am trying to compare against the value of that variable

Comment: `That will then compare against the name of the variable ` => you obviously did not try. `when: "'job_running_check_key' != 'Running'"` <= this would check against var name, but => `when: job_running_check_key != 'Running'` is definitely using its value. A good read on this subject: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names